# Can someone explain how the Cauchy's mean value theorem applies here

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How isnt this a exeption to the Cauchy's mean value theorem?


$f(x)=x^2+x;g(x)=x^3;x∈[−1,1]$

Because $g'(0)=0$ which is a contradiction to the third condition that:


$g'(x)\neq 0 ;\forall x∈(−1,1)$

Comment: g'(x) does not exist is the thrid condition and that g'(x) = 0 does not prove that it does not exist.  It is still a valid third condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, an example cannot possibly contradict a *condition* of a statement. A contradiction would be a situation in which all the conditions hold, but not te conclusion.

In the second place, the conditions of Cauchy's mean value theorem are not in the same order for all authors. So, your “third condition” is not a good way of expressing it.

Finally, the theorem [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy%27s_mean_value_theorem) that there is a $c\in(-1,1)$ such that$$\bigl(f(1)-f(-1)\bigr)g'(c)=\bigl(g(1)-g(-1)\bigr)f'(c),$$which happens to be true. So, there is no contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology , english is not my native language .Thank you so much for the answer.